# Replace All Characters with a set of characters

Tags: c++, regex, string, char

I am trying to replace a each character in a string with another set of characters

```
for example a -> ABC
            b -> BCA
            d -> CBA
```

but i seem to be having problems with this seemingly simple task

so far i have

```
#include <isotream>
#include "Class.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  int main(){
      string test;
      cin >> test;
      Class class;
      cout << class.returnString(test);
}
```

in my Class that i am calling i have

```
#include "Class.h" //which has <string> <iostream> and std
static string phrase;
static string whole;
static int place;
Class::Class(){
if (phrase != ""){
    phrase = "";
}
if (whole != ""){
    whole = "";
}
if (place == NULL){
    place = 0;
}
}

void Class::reader(string x){
    char symbol = x.at(place);
    while (symbol != '\0'){
       place++;
       replacer(symbol);
       reader(x);
   }
}
void Class::replacer(char x){
    if (char x = 'a'){
        phrase = "hola";
    }
    if (char x = 'b'){
        phrase = "hi";
    }
    knitter();
 }
void Class::knitter(){
    whole = whole + phrase;
}

string Class::returnString(string x){
    reader(x);
    return whole;
}
```

i keep getting an invalid string position as an error when i try to run it with just "a" in the test string.

Comment: `place` is an int that you never initialize properly. In the constructor of `Class` you check whether it's null, but it's an `int`, not a pointer. So it is not initialized, the result of that comparison is undefined, `place` is not set to 0, and in `reader` you access string `x` at `place`, which as said is undefined. However it would help if you edited your question to explain at which line the error occurs; I guess at the one I've indicated, but still I'd like to hear it from you.

Comment: `if (char x = 'a')` - oh god. Please turn on the compiler's warnings.

Comment: In addition to @FabioTurati and @KarolyHorvath comments, `if (char x = 'a'){ ... }`, the `=`'s does not check for equality, it's the assignment operator. `==`'s checks for equality. Not to mention that `x` is already declared as a `char` in the method's signature (`void Class::replacer(char x)`), don't declare variables in an `if` statement.

Comment: @FabioTurati I am not sure how to check where my error is, as i am relatively new to coding. I am currently using microsoft visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop. When i run the program, it starts up fine, but when i enter "a" into the console and hit enter, the program crashes and I am brought the either xmemory0 or xstring. (depending on whether i have `place = 0` in `void Class::reader(string x)` outside the `while loop`. In `xstring` i am brought to `_Xout_of_range("invaluid string position")`. In xmemory0, I am brought to a `if(_Count == 0)... else if(...)` statement

Comment: Well then, use a debugger! You can step through your code, one line at a time, and see what happens. Alternatively, a lazy solution is to fill your code with `cout`s that let you understand what is going on. This is for isolating the point where the problem shows up. But in the meanwhile, check the things we have pointed out. The problem you have (invalid string position) probably depends on what I said (`place` is not initialised), but the other errors are maybe even worse - in an `if` you must use the **double** equal, that is, `if (char x == 'a')`, otherwise it won't do what you want.

Comment: @FabioTurati i seem to have gotten it to work using `getline()` but im also using an `ifstream` to read a file that contains the "translation". However, when i run the program something like "abc" becomes "&" without quotation marks of course. I am wondering why this is happening and maybe a something to fix it

Comment: Since I don't know what your code is now, you must either edit this question heavily, or ask a new one. Maybe a new one is better, because most comments and the answer that are already here would no longer make sense if you edited this one. If you ask a new one, add a link to it here. Either way, make sure to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we have something to work on.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop below 'symbol' will always be 'a'.

```
void Class::reader(string x){
    char symbol = x.at(place);
    while (symbol != '\0'){
       place++;
       replacer(symbol);
       reader(x);
   }
}
```

You need to read 'x' inside while loop otherwise your while loop never terminates. Calling knitter in an infinite program will make "whole" look like: "holaholaholahola...." and your program will eventually run out of stack memory which is probably why you are getting invalid string position error. Also, as a general rule I would avoid using static variables. If you change the program as below it might work:

```
void Class::reader(string x){
    char symbol = x.at(place);
    while (symbol != '\0'){
       place++;
       replacer(symbol);
       reader(x);
       symbol = x.at(place);
   }
}
```

Comment: He might want to fix the `void Class::replacer(char x) { ... }` method as well...